# SQL Server Convert String to DATETIME failing

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, datetime, type-conversion

I'm using Laravel 5.5 for refactoring one web applications and here I have a raw query where I need to convert a date string that I got from a user input using PHP to a `DATETIME` in `Sql Server` in order to compare it to some other columns. This is a small part of the query where things fail:

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @the_date DATETIME;
        DECLARE @floor VARCHAR(10);
        SET @the_date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '?', 105));
        SET @floor = '?' + '%';

        SELECT fo_bs.SeatCir,
                fo_bs.UserDAS,
                fo_bs.FromDate,
                fo_bs.ToDate,
                fo_bs.Status
        FROM BookedSeats fo_bs
        WHERE fo_bs.FromDate <= @the_date
            AND fo_bs.ToDate >= @the_date
            AND fo_bs.SeatCir LIKE @floor
```

I didn't write the query, I just adapted it for Laravel raw query for the refactoring(it's very complex and I don't want to rewrite it all using the Query Builder) of the web application and this is the error thrown by Laravel:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 241 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQLExecute[241] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260) 
(SQL: SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @the_date VARCHAR(20); DECLARE @floor VARCHAR(10); SET @the_date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '03-04-2019 00:04:00', 105)); SET @floor = 'OV6.' + '%'; SELECT fo_bs.SeatCir, fo_bs.UserDAS, fo_bs.FromDate, fo_bs.ToDate, fo_bs.Status FROM FlexibleOffice.dbo.BookedSeats fo_bs WHERE fo_bs.FromDate <= @the_date AND fo_bs.ToDate >= @the_date AND fo_bs.SeatCir LIKE @floor )
```

Now if I copy the whole SQL from the error(the 3rd row) and paste it in SQL Server Management Studio and give it a run, it gets the rows perfectly and this is why I'm so confused.

Is there any strict mode available in the odb_driver for Laravel? I tried setting 
            `'strict' => false`
in `config/database.php` for my connection configuration but no luck with that.

Comment: Your code contains `CONVERT(DATETIME...)` whereas the error contains `CONVERT(DATE,...)`. Which one is correct?

Comment: @SalmanA yea, sorry.. I tried a lot of combinations but with no successful result. I must've copied from another tab but the idea is the same.. I edited my post

Comment: Your code has a smell. You're converting a string to date but saving it as varchar(20). Change `DECLARE @the_date VARCHAR(20)` to `DECLARE @the_date DATE` and see it it helps.

Comment: Yea. I changed it but it's the same error.. I don't know.. It's very weird because if I copy/paste the code in SSMS it runs perfectly

Comment: Are you referencing same databases in SSMS and the laravel application?

Comment: Yes.. it's only one table called BookedSeats